# What is the correct way to return a tuple and an integer simulataneously, and then unpack them?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

At the end of a function generateKeys(), which is in a class called RSA, I have:

```
...        
#now calculate d (the decryption key)
d=(k*phi_n+1)/e

public_key = (n,e)

return (public_key), d
```

As you can see I am trying to return a tuple (n,e) and an integer d. But when I call the function as shown below I run into an "object not iterable" error.

```
RSA1=RSA()
publicK, privateK = RSA1.generateKeys()
```

I can't find any examples where a tuple and an int are returned together. 
Is there any reason why doesn't this work and how it should be done?
Thanks very much

**edit:
Solved.** The problem was a second return statment that didn't return any arguments: Python detected the possibility of returning nothing on one path and flagged the error as "None type object not iterable" which confused me for a while. Thanks to all who helped figure it out.

Comment: I don't see why your code would fail as it is... You need to provide a bit more, like the full body of `generateKeys()`, or at least a [mre].

Comment: What you show in the first block is correct (although the parentheses around `public_key` are unnecessary).  Something else is wrong.

Comment: You do not iterate - the error for unpacking is different. You iterate later in your code but do not show it - please post the exact full stacktrace and check the line it is pointing at

Comment: Quite right @chepner. Sorry, this question needs to be deleted now - I was barking up the wrong tree. I had a second return statement that was messing things up.

Answer (score 2):

In this line

```
return (public_key), d
```

You are returning a tuple, and an integer. Although they are automatically packed into a tuple by python, that’s how it works. It’s the same as saying `some_val = 1, 2, 3` which is interpreted as a tuple in python.

In essence it’s returned as this:

```
((n, e), d)
```

So to get the values as they were returned use:

```
publicK, privateK = RSA1.generateKeys()
```

So you have the tuple in `publicK` and the value of `d` in `privateK`

Or to get each value independently, use:

```
(publicKn, publicKe), privateK = RSA1.generateKeys()
```

Answer (score -1):

To declare a 1-tuple, you need to put a single comma *inside* the tuple:

```
return (public_key,), d
```

This is to avoid ambiguity with `(public_key)`, which is just `public_key` wrapped in parentheses.

You *can* but *don't have to* do this with higher-order tuples (e.g. `(1, 2, 3,)` is valid and identical to `(1, 2, 3)`), but due to the ambiguity, it's required if your tuple contains exactly one element. A zero-element tuple can be invoked with `()`.

Comment: `public_key` is already a tuple.